# ¿Cómo cambiar columnas separadas por espacios a columnas separadas por comas en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo esta lista de números que quisiera unir por una coma, sin embargo, hay espacios en blanco debajo de las columnas con números que quisiera conservar y cambiar por NaN.

A lo que me refiero es que me gustaría hacer que cada columna quede separada por comas, para que sea más sencillo de trabajar con pandas.

```
398.4   7620  -17.0  -32.8     24   0.61    295     21  333.2  335.6  333.4
300.0   9680  -32.7  -43.7     33   0.27    325     34  339.2  340.3  339.2
259.7  10668  -40.8                         315     40  341.6         341.6
250.0  10930  -42.9                         310     40  342.1         342.1
```

Quisiera que se viera así:

```
398.4,7620,-17.0,-32.8,24,0.61,295,21,333.2,335.6,333.4
300.0,9680,-32.7,-43.7,33,0.27,325,34,339.2,340.3,339.2
259.7,10668,-40.8,NaN,NaN,NaN,315,40,341.6,NaN,,341.6
250.0,10930,-42.9,NaN,NaN,NaN,310,40,342.1,NaN,342.1
```

Me gustaría saber si alguien conoce una función que me pueda ayudar a hacer esto, o una idea de cómo hacerlo porque realmente no se me ocurre una manera de hacerlo, he buscado funciones en pandas o funciones de numpy que me ayuden a hacer esto pero no he encontrado ninguna. Por otro lado vi la función join pero no sé cómo podría aplicarla a esta tabla

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Hola thrashrider, la "lista de números" dónde la tienes originalmente ¿En un archivo de texto?¿Un DataFrame?...

Comment: Hola FJSevilla! Está en un documento de texto.

Comment: Vale, es decir las columnas están separadas por un número indeterminado y no uniforme de espacios... ¿tiene cabecera con el nombre de las columnas o solo filas como las que muestras?

Comment: Sí, los espacios varían entre columnas y no, no tienen encabezados así como la pongo es como la tengo.

Comment: Con la forma en que esta estructurado tu actual documento de texto veo un poco difícil implementar cualquier código. ¿Esta en tu poder la capacidad de alterar ese archivo o lo recibiste así?

Comment: ¿El último dígito de cada columna tampoco aparece siempre en la misma posición del String de las filas? en el fragmento que mostrás parecería que sí. Si es así podrías usar esa información para saber donde hay que remplazar por NaN.

Comment: Lo recibí así, realmente tengo muchos archivos de esos que tengo que manipular y viene en un formato que se me dificulta para analizar en Python, son datos meteorológicos de muchos años, ese es un ejemplo de todo el resto

Comment: A veces aparece, a veces no, son datos meteorológicos y las variables no siempre se miedieron igual pero se me ha dificultado mucho trabajar con eso.

Answer (score 2):

La gracia (desgracia más bien...) está en que no se les ocurrió nada mejor que usar espacios tanto para los valores `NaN` como para el separador entre columnas.... Sería trivial con `pandas.read_table` o `read_csv` si no fuera por este pequeño detalle y los valores NaN fueran cualquier otro carácter o cadena, bastaría con usar `sep="\s+"` o  `delim_whitespace=True` y el parser de Python podría parsearlo sin problemas.

Para empeorarlo todo más si cabe, los ficheros no tienen cabeceras con los títulos de las columnas. Esto simplificaría enormemente todo ya que podríamos usar esta fila (que no tiene NaN lógicamente) para obtener el número de columnas y sus límites.

En definitiva, a priori no sabemos el número de columnas ni podemos diferenciar entre lo que es un separador y una celda vacía, pero nada es imposible. Si asumimos algunas condiciones que se cumplen en tu ejemplo:

- Al menos la tabla está bien hecha, es decir, las columnas están bien alineadas:

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

  Esto es imprescindible, si lo anterior no se cumple no veo la forma de resolver el problema, no al menos de forma determinista.
- No hay una columna con todos sus valores `NaN`. Esto no es realmente un problema en el parseo, simplemente esta "supuesta columna" (porque no sabemos ni nosotros si solo es un espaciado muy amplio y no una columna vacía, a no ser que sepamos seguro que el fichero tiene x columnas) sería ignorada.
- No hay espacios en los valores de cada celda. Esto se podría solventar dado el caso modificando la expresión regular, siempre y cuando los valores estén correctamente acotados (p.e `"Stack Overflow"` o `|Stack Overflow|`)

Con ello se puede hacer un enfoque más o menos simple, la idea sería la siguiente:

- Usar una expresión regular que nos permita separar cada "columna", entendiendo por "columna" cualquier número de espacios en blanco (o ninguno) seguido de cualquier número de caracteres que no lo sean. La idea es obtener por cada fila los valores de las columnas no nulas y el índice del último carácter del mismo.

  Esto se puede conseguir con una expresión regular del tipo `'(\s{0,})(\S{1,})'` dónde `(\s{0,})` captura cero o cualquier número de espacios y `(\S{1,})` uno o más caracteres que no sean espacios.

  Con `re.finditer` podemos obtener un objeto `Match` por cada coincidencia que nos permite obtener el índice final (índice del carácter justo antes de la línea roja en la imagen anterior) con `Match.end()` y el valor de la columna con `Match.group(2)` (grupo generado por `(\S{1,})`)
- Con los dos valores anteriores vamos a crear un diccionario por cada fila, dónde la clave es el índice final de la columna y el valor el contenido de la misma. Al final tendremos una lista con un diccionario por fila.
- Ahora la clave está en detectar todas las columnas y sus índices, para ello recorremos las claves de todos los diccionarios y nos quedamos con los índices únicos. Un conjunto (`set`) nos ayuda en ello eficientemente.
- Con esto no queda más que recorrer la lista de diccionarios e ir guardando las filas en el nuevo csv, cuando el diccionario de la fila no tenga una columna (falte la clave de su índice) añadimos un "NaN", `dict.get` está pensado para esto.

Esta sería una posible implementación:

```
import csv
import re



patt = re.compile(r'(\s{0,})(\S{1,})')

with open("entrada.txt") as archivo_entrada:
    tabla = [{math.end(): math.group(2) for math in patt.finditer(fila.rstrip())}
                                            for fila in archivo_entrada
            ]

indices = list(set(indice for fila in tabla for indice in fila))
indices.sort()

numero_columnas = len(indices)

with open("salida.csv", "w", newline='') as archivo_salida:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(archivo_salida, delimiter=',')
    gen = ((fila.get(i, "NaN") for i in indices) for fila in tabla )
    csv_writer.writerows(gen)
```

Para un archivo de partida más diabólico que el que muestras:

> ```
> 398.4                                                                      
>         9680                                                               
>               -40.8                                                        
>                                     0.61                                   
>                                24                                          
>                      -32.8                                                 
>                                                     21                     
>                                             295                            
>                                                         333.2              
>                                                                       333.4
>                                                                335.6
> ```

Obtenemos:

> ```
> 398.4,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
> NaN,9680,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
> NaN,NaN,-40.8,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
> NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,0.61,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
> NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,24,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
> NaN,NaN,NaN,-32.8,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
> NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,21,NaN,NaN,NaN
> NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,295,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
> NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,333.2,NaN,NaN
> NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,333.4
> NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,335.6,NaN
> ```

Ahora es simple la lectura por Pandas, para tu ejemplo:

> ```
> >>> import pandas as pd
> >>> df = pd.read_csv("salida.csv", header=None)
>
> >>> df
>
>        0      1     2     3     4     5    6   7      8      9     10
> 0  398.4   7620 -17.0 -32.8  24.0  0.61  295  21  333.2  335.6  333.4
> 1  300.0   9680 -32.7 -43.7  33.0  0.27  325  34  339.2  340.3  339.2
> 2  259.7  10668 -40.8   NaN   NaN   NaN  315  40  341.6    NaN  341.6
> 3  250.0  10930 -42.9   NaN   NaN   NaN  310  40  342.1    NaN  342.1
> ```

Con el ejemplo "malvado" mostrado antes, es fácil  comprender que necesitamos cargar todo el fichero en memoria para asegurarnos de obtener todas las columnas y sus límites. Si estamos tratando fichero enormes y estamos limitados por la RAM esto podría ser un problema. Hay varias formas de lidiar con esto aunque son menos "elegantes", por ejemplo:

- Requerir la intervención de un cerebro humano y su magnífica eficiencia para detectar patrones, para que abra el fichero en un editor y proporcione manualmente al proceso una fila o varias filas que contengan todas las columnas en su conjunto o bien que de los indices directamente. Esto permitiría saltarse el primer paso y podríamos procesar el fichero linea a  linea.
- Otra opción es leer el fichero dos veces, una para detectar el número de columnas y otro para el parseo, pero permitiría no usar apenas memoria concurrentemente a costa de duplicar el trabajo...

Comment: ¡Impresionante! Lastima que no te puedo dar un +1 por la idea y otro +1 por el código!

Comment: Estoy anonadado con toda tu explicación, muy buena explicación y todo lo entendí muy bien, te agradezco mucho, apenas lo aplique te comento.